# Is there a way to efficiently split data into columns based on key in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I want to split a column where values are in dictionary into columns. Assuming I have millions of row, how can I do it without using for loop?

Currently, This is what I am doing:

```
s = {"alpha":['apple','ball']*300,"data":[{"source":'CNN','time':'two'},{"license":'CNN','time':'two'}]*300}
pp=pd.DataFrame(s)
start = 0
st=pd.DataFrame()
intermediate =100
while start< len(pp):
    few = pp.loc[start:intermediate,:]
#     print(few)
    few_edges1=pd.concat([few.drop(['data'], axis=1), few['data'].apply(pd.Series)], axis=1)

    st=pd.concat([st,few_edges1])
    start =  intermediate+1
    intermediate = intermediate+100
#     if start % 500000==0:

print(st.shape)
st.head()
```

Please note that dictionary might not have same keys. In this example, there are only 3 different keys but I might have tens of keys in real data.

Thanks,

Sam

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, it's just:

```
st = (pp.drop('data', axis=1)
        .join(pd.DataFrame.from_records(pp['data'].values))
     )
```

Output (`st.head()`):

```
   alpha source time license
0  apple    CNN  two     NaN
1   ball    NaN  two     CNN
2  apple    CNN  two     NaN
3   ball    NaN  two     CNN
4  apple    CNN  two     NaN
```

Comment: This is so much faster than that for loop and code I had. Thank you!! This code was able to convert 2 mil row in 15 sec compared to 15 min in my code!!

Comment: just as an addon, do u need the duplicates?

Comment: @sammywemmy, this was just an example data. In real dataset, there is no duplicates. However, if I don't want duplicates, what can I do?

Comment: ```drop_duplicates``` works fine. I was just checking, since it didnt make sense to have the dupes. all good.